# Regular expression - Negative lookahead

Tags: java, regex, string, pattern-matching

Using the following expression:

```
(?<!XYZ\d{8})(?>REF[A-Z]*)?(\d{3}+)(\d{6}+)(\d{3}+)
```

I am getting unexpected matches. Please could you explain why the following matches occur:

- Input `XYZ12345678123456789123` - Matches on `123456781234` - I was expecting it to only match on `123456789123` because it is the only sequence not preceded by `(?<!XYZ\d{8})`

Weirdly enough, if i use `XYZ12345678REF123456789876` as input, it returns a match on `123456789876` but not `REF123456789876`. It correctly ignored the `XYZ12345678`, but it didn't pick up the optional REF characters.

Basically what i want to achieve is to extract a 12 digit identifier from a string that contains two identifiers. The first identifier has the format `XYZ\d{8}` and the second identifier has the format `(?>REF[A-Z]*)?(\d{3}+)(\d{6}+)(\d{3}+)`

To avoid a match on the wrong 12 digits in a string such as `XYZ12345678123456789123`, i want to say - get the twelve digits as long as the digits are not part of an `XYZ\d{8}` type identifier.

### Edit

Here are a couple of examples of what i want to achieve

```
XYZ12345678123456789123  match on 123456789123
123456789123 match on 123456789123
XYZ12345678REF123456789123 should match on REF123456789123
12345678912 no match because not 12 digits
REF123456789123 match on REF123456789123
REF12345678912 no match because not 12 digits
XYZ12345678123456789123ABC match on 123456789123
XYZ123456789123  No match
XYZ1234567891234  no match
```

Comment: `123456789123 because it is the only sequence not preceded by (?<!XYZ\d{8})` What a minute. in `XYZ12345678123456789123` before `123456789123` you have `XYZ12345678` which matches exactly `XYZ\d{8}`. How do you think look-behind works? In case of `123456781234` it indeed doesn't have `XYZ\d{8}` before and matches `(?>REF[A-Z]*)?(\d{3}+)(\d{6}+)(\d{3}+)` so it seems to be working correctly.

Comment: In the string `XYZ12345678123456789123` should it not have matched to `123456789123` (i.e. the last 12 digits) instead of `123456781234` (i.e. the first 12 digits)? I thought the expression `(?<!XYZ\d{8})` will cause it to match to the latter and not the former.

Comment: To make helping you easier please provide more examples of input and expected output. Currently I suspect that using positive look behind `(?<=...)` instead of negative one `(?<!...)` could solve your problem, but I am not sure how all your inputs can look like.

Comment: Please see the edit - I must admit im just learning about positive/negative look behinds so i might have got it wrong in the expression.

Comment: Can the string contain something else than the identifiers? How about using an anchor and including the `XYZ` identifier in the match [like this](http://regex101.com/r/mC9yK3)?

Comment: I wanted it to only match the 12 digit identifier i.e. if there is a match it has to be the 12 digit id and not any other ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You ware almost there. Change `(?<!XYZ\\d{8})` to `(?<!XYZ\\d{0,7})`. You need to check if your match is not part of previous identifier `XYZ\\d{8}` which means it cant have

- `XYZ`
- `XYZ1`
- `XYZ12`
- ...
- `XYZ1234567`

before it.

---

Demo based on your examples

```
String[] data ={
        "XYZ12345678123456789123",          //123456789123
        "123456789123",                     //123456789123
        "XYZ12345678REF123456789123 ",      //REF123456789123
        "12345678912",                      //no match because not 12 digits
        "REF123456789123",                  //REF123456789123
        "REF12345678912",                   //no match because not 12 digits
        "XYZ12345678123456789123ABC",       //123456789123
        "XYZ123456789123",                  //no match
        "XYZ1234567891234",                 //no match
};


Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<!XYZ\\d{0,7})(?>REF[A-Z]*)?(\\d{3}+)(\\d{6}+)(\\d{3}+)");
for (String s:data){
    System.out.printf("%-30s",s);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find())
        System.out.print("match: "+m.group());
    System.out.println();
}
```

output:

```
XYZ12345678123456789123       match: 123456789123
123456789123                  match: 123456789123
XYZ12345678REF123456789123    match: REF123456789123
12345678912                   
REF123456789123               match: REF123456789123
REF12345678912                
XYZ12345678123456789123ABC    match: 123456789123
XYZ123456789123               
XYZ1234567891234
```

Comment: Ah ok this explains what was wrong with my expression - Thanks. 
Do you if the format {0,7} in lookbehinds is only allowed in certain regex engines? I tested the above and it works in Java but not in http://regex101.com/r/aN8mT6 (Lookbehinds need to be zero-width)

Comment: It seems so. You can try using http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html instead. It has regex engine used in Java.

Answer (score 1):

The engine starts looking at the first character in the string.
If the string is "ABCDEF" and the regex is `(?<!C)...`
Looking at `A`, it sees there is no `C` to the left of it.

The assertion being satisfied, it then matches `ABC`.

Assertions just test the characters around it at the current position it is at.
They don't force the engine to find `C` first and match the char's after it.

**edit**

From your examples you would need somethin like this, that is anchored.
If not anchored, it could be harder.

Also, Java doesn't have branch reset, so you will have to see which group
cluster matched.

```
 #  "^(?:(?:XYZ\\d{8})(\\d{3})(\\d{6})(\\d{3})|(?:REF)(\\d{3})(\\d{6})(\\d{3})|(\\d{3})(\\d{6})(\\d{3}))"

 ^ 
 (?:
      (?: XYZ \d{8} )
      ( \d{3} )            # (1)
      ( \d{6} )            # (2)
      ( \d{3} )            # (3)
   |  
      (?: REF )
      ( \d{3} )            # (4)
      ( \d{6} )            # (5)
      ( \d{3} )            # (6)
   |  
      ( \d{3} )            # (7)
      ( \d{6} )            # (8)
      ( \d{3} )            # (9)
 )
```

alternative,

```
 #  "^(?:(?:XYZ\\d{8})|(?:REF))?(\\d{3})(\\d{6})(\\d{3})"

 ^ 
 (?:
      (?: XYZ \d{8} )
   |  (?: REF )
 )?
 ( \d{3} )                 # (1)
 ( \d{6} )                 # (2)
 ( \d{3} )                 # (3)
```

Comment: Thanks - I want to avoid having anchors in the final expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if it's match is not part of previous identifier XYZ\d{8} which means it cant have

```
XYZ
XYZ1
XYZ12
...
XYZ1234567
```

before it.

Also, Java doesn't have branch reset, so you will have to see which group
cluster matched.

I will make the change

```
 (?<!XYZ\\d{8})    to    (?<!XYZ\\d{0,7}).
```

hope this helps.